# Loading too many images, slows down my website

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax, scrollbar

I am trying to create an image gallery. My scroll bar gets rough and slows down when i try to add some 20 different images. Any suggestions??

Comment: specific more, means your coding.

Comment: without any more info virtually impossible. There are a number of things you can do, but without seeing what is actually done at the moment, it's hard to suggest upgrades..

Comment: Using ajax, i am displaying list of images from a php file.
Images are displayed inside a Div with a scroll bar. This scroll bar gets slow.

Answer (score 3):

- Make sure you add the `width` and `height` attributes. On my webpage when I added them, for some reason it loaded a little bit faster on Safari and Chrome but made no difference on the other browsers.
- You can also try [lazy loading](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) your images. It really makes a difference.
- Make sure you resize your images to the size they are going to be displayed on your webpage.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is vague, is it the images or scroll bars that are slow?

If images:

Never resize your images with css width height properties. This will load the entire image and be very slow. Instead resize images before uploading them, or have a thumb generator resize them on upload.

If the image is small (less than 100 pixels height or width) you can reduce it's quality when generating the thumb, so the file-size is smaller but to no noticable affect.

Use the correct file format.
 - gif for animation
 - png for small inconsequential graphics like logos and icons
 - jpg for higher quality graphics like images

Are you gzipping content before sending it on the server?

Use a CDN for your images like AWS S3 yes, but DO NOT USE flick/picassa as they will 'look up' your image before serving it, which will be much slower.
Using just a CDN (AWS S3) will be better than your current hosting as they've been optimised for quick look ups, reducing the wait time by 50-90% compared to most web hosts.

Use only one CDN, once the DNS look up has taken place for the domain your browser will cache it.

If your site uses cookies or sessions store the images on a different URL (this can be a subdomain of your site), so that the cookies and session data aren't sent with each image request (slowing it down).

If the graphics are re-used set a time out parameter on them (a couple of months in the future), so that the browser caches them locally.

EDIT: I would also agree that loading images on demand/visibility in webpage is a very good practice.

If scroll bars:

Are you using custom scroll bars and or a custom scroll event?
If so, you may want to put a threshold (I recommend 100ms) for how often your resize event can be fired. Or manually fire the resize event after loading the images, as if in your scenario you know when the images have been loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Try lazy loading your images using jQuery. Here's a plugin: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Here's an example of when I've used lazy loading: https://www.lunatickets.co.uk (scroll down the page and watch the images).

Also make sure the browser isn't resizing your images! Make sure you've optimised them for the web!

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure you add width/height attributes to your img tags - other
  wise your browser/website layout will "jump around" as it loads them.
- If your inserting images try resizing them to the appropriate
  width/height before you load them. Your browser will run slower if it
  is resizing the large images to display smaller.

Comment: yeah i am jus displaying thumbnail size, 50px * 50px

Comment: can you provide an live example of your page. Theres not much to go by after these pointers..

Comment: what do you mean by appropriate height and width?? for now i am jus re sizing all images to same size

Comment: how are you resizing the images? Are you doing it before uploading to your site, or are you simply resizing with CSS?

Comment: make sure your thumbnails actual size is 50x50pixels (not just being displayed at that size.) Also, if you havn't already, add `width="50" height="50"` to each image tag.

Comment: I am just displaying the big image with size 50*50 using css. Because i need the big image later

Comment: Then, the browser has to download the big image, and shrink it to 50*50. And with many big images, that is a problem.

Comment: so what should i do for this?? I only have big images on my server.

Comment: you will need to resize your images via the server. search and try "phpThumb"

Comment: I tried re sizing all images manually and load them. I am still getting that problem

Comment: You tried? or you actually did resize them? Make sure you have the attributes: `width="50" height="50"`. How are you positioning the elements? Are they inside divs/lis etc.? What CSS? Can you provide an example?

Comment: I resized all image files using picture manager and displayed it. I am creating a table inside a div with scroll bar Each td again has div with a image of size 50*50

Comment: Try add float:left to your images. This will change them from inline to block elements, hopefully making the table render better. Also, make sure you have a valid doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to load all images at once.

Slideshows like this: http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/slideshow/, they only load the showed image plus some of the next.
The gallery I last used loaded the current image and the next 10 images. I don't remember the name, but I think that is the way to do it.

Comment: I am not looking for slideshow view. My usecase is just to display all images thumbnail views.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried keeping your images on S3, Flickr or Picasso? Let their servers take the hit for the HTTP requests